# Scaling image after rotating image in canvas with java script

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, rotation

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I want to make image editor in canvas with java script. Everything is working how I wanted, except when I first rotate and than try to scale image.

I want this to work like when you rotate and scale images in photoshop but my image move slightly across x and y axis when you try to scale  after rotating them.

This is my example of code [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/nj4kha5o/)

```
function scale(){

    var dx = mouse_curent_x - mouse_start_x;
    var dy = mouse_curent_y - mouse_start_y;



        if(img.scale_direction == "right"){
            img.width += dx;
        }
        if(img.scale_direction == "left"){
            img.width += -dx;
            img.left += dx;
        }
        if(img.scale_direction == "bottom"){
            img.height += dy;
        }
        if(img.scale_direction == "top"){
            img.height += -dy;
            img.top += dy;
        }
        if(img.scale_direction == "top-left"){
            img.height += -dy;
            img.top += dy;
            img.width += -dx;
            img.left += dx; 
        }
        if(img.scale_direction == "top-right"){
            img.height += -dy;
            img.top += dy;
            img.width += dx;
        }
        if(img.scale_direction == "bottom-right"){
            img.height += dy;
            img.width += dx;
        }
        if(img.scale_direction == "bottom-left"){
            img.height += dy;
            img.width += -dx;
            img.left += dx;             
        }


    mouse_start_x = mouse_curent_x;
    mouse_start_y = mouse_curent_y;

    draw(true, true)
}

function rotate(){

    var imageCenterX = img.left+(img.width/2);
    var imageCenterY = img.top+(img.height/2);

    var a = { x: mouse_curent_x, y: mouse_curent_y };
    var b = { x: imageCenterX, y: imageCenterY };
    var c = { x: mouse_start_x, y: mouse_start_y };

    var dir = ccw(a, b, c);

    var radians = getAngle(a, b, c);
    var cursor = dir == -1 ? getAngle(a, b, {x: b.x+1, y: b.y}) : getAngle(a, b, {x: b.x+1, y: b.y})+Math.PI;

    img.angle = dir == -1 ? -radians + img.old_angle : radians + img.old_angle;

    draw(true, true)
}


function draw(withAnchors, withSelection){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();

    // Rotate
    var tX = img.left + img.width/2;
    var tY = img.top + img.height/2;
    ctx.translate(tX, tY);

    ctx.rotate(img.angle);

    // ctx.scale(img.scale_width, img.scale_height);

    ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width/2, -img.height/2, img.width, img.height);
    ctx.restore();

    if(withSelection) drawSelection();
    if(withAnchors) drawDragAnchor();
}
```

In the jsfiddle example you can rotate image by clicking on blue rectangle and scale image clicking on the pink one.

Comment: Is all that code really needed to get to the root-cause of the problem. Please visit [ask] for guidance on how to include ony the relevant code in your post

Comment: I shorted my code to only tree functions that cause problem.